# C++: no instance of constructor matches the argument list

Tags: c++, constructor

I want to return a `Piece` from function. `Piece` is an abstract class parent for all of my pieces.

```
Piece* Board::getPieceBySign(char sign, Player& _player1, Player& _player2, Player& _emptyPlayer, int row, int col) const
{
    switch (sign) {
        case Piece::B_KING:
            // Example:     King(Player& p, const int row, const int col, Board& b);
            return new King(_player1, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::B_QUEEN:
            return new Queen(_player1, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::B_ROOK:
            return new Rook(_player1, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::B_KNIGHT:
            return new Knight(_player1, sign, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::B_BISHOP:
            return new Bishop(_player1, sign, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::B_PAWN:
            return new Pawn(_player1, sign, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::W_KING:
            return new King(_player2, sign, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::W_QUEEN:
            return new Queen(_player2, sign, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::W_ROOK:
            return new Rook(_player2, sign, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::W_KNIGHT:
            return new Knight(_player2, sign, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::W_BISHOP:
            return new Bishop(_player2, sign, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::W_PAWN:
            return new Pawn(_player2, sign, row, col, *this);

        case Piece::EMPTY:
            return nullptr;
    }
}
```

In every line, I get an error that says the arguments are not as they should be. And it's not true. Maybe because I try to initialize memory inside of a `switch`?

`no instance of constructor matches the argument list`

**King.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Queen.h"

class King :
    public Queen
{
public:
    King(Player& p, const int row, const int col, Board& b);
    bool isWayfree(const int destRow, const int destCol) const override;
    bool isLeagalMove(const int destRow, const int destCol) const override;
};
```

Comment: _"Maybe because I try to initialize memory inside of a switch?"_ Nope, you can do that there. It's because of what that error message says.

Comment: Since we can't see the constructors you're trying to call the only assumption we can make is that the compiler is correct. The full error message copy/pasted would help and a [mcve] would eliminate all doubt.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the constructors for `King`, for example.

Comment: Ok. I'll add it now

Comment: The function you're in is `const`, so `this` is also `const`, meaning it cannot be converted to the `Board&` required.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The question includes the code where the error occurs and the code that triggers the error. There's even an accepted answer! No way it "needs debugging details".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Piece* Board::getPieceBySign(char sign, Player& _player1,
            Player& _player2, Player& _emptyPlayer, int row, int col) const
```

That trailing `const` indicates that this is a `const` method. In `const` methods, the `this` object is `const`. That's what it means to be a `const` method.

```
    King(Player& p, const int row, const int col, Board& b);
```

`*this` gets passed in as a last parameter to this constructor, however the parameter is a `Board &`, and not a `const Board &`. This is the reason for the compilation error. You either have to make that a `const Board &b`, or `getPieceBySign` must be a non-`const` class method.

Now that you know the reason, you can go back and look at your compiler's full error message, including everything that follows the initial "no instance of constructor matches the argument list"; and you should be able to see that's exactly what your compiler is telling you, in its own way.